# My.Forms Question

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

My current project has 10 or so forms, however when using the itellisense within visual studio only 3 show up within the My.Forms property. I would have imagined that the forms would have been added to this as they are added to the project.

Is there a setting somewhere which needs to tweaked to ensure they show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the above problem. If you pass any values into the constructor for your form then it will not show up within the my.forms collection.